# AppleScript: String and File Manpiulation

Tags: python, file-io, applescript

After collecting a list of files with an mdfind() script, I now need to copy each of the files found and also to store their original paths for later. Essentially, I have to move a huge and widely distributed number of old AppleWorks files to a new volume, manually update them, and then replace the original files with new, updated versions *at the same locations and with the same filenames* (but not extensions or document type).

As I am new to AppleScript, I am doing the file manipulation with Python and am only using AppleScript to locate the documents (as file extensions will not suffice for my purposes, I need to look at apple metatags via mdfind).

But the document I can produce with my AppleScript—a list of file paths—is using the apple "\r" new line delimiter and consequently I cannot import this to python easily.

My Apple Script:

```
set the_script to "mdfind   kMDItemKind=='*AppleWorks*'"
set the_text to (do shell script the_script)
set the_doc to (choose file)
write the_text to the_doc
```

Which produces a .txt file with all sorts of lovely path names, but python reads it as one enormous string.

How do I either

a) tell Apple Script to append a custom delimiter to each line (ie. "\n")

or

b) how do I tell Apple Script to copy each file it's found to a new location while preserving the original files and keeping a record of their paths?

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE  @Kindall**

This is the error python throws when I try to pipe in the `mdfind` command:

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File     "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
 File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any ideas? I am primarily a web-developer trying to nub my way through some other languages to avoid manually sorting through 2-3k files on my bosses ancient mac laptop, haha (and I corrected the typographic errors in your original code, I am not trying to run it verbatim).

Comment: Try delimiting the lines with `-e`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the advice from Kindall, myself and some folks at my lab put together a solution that works well with Apple but uses entirely python, as follows:

```
import os
import subprocess

outfile = os.open("test",os.O_CREAT)
os.close(outfile)
outfile = os.open("test",os.O_RDWR)
command = ["mdfind","kMDItemKind == '*AppleWorks*'"]
subpipe = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=outfile)
```

Which produces a text file in the directory from which the script is run. Thanks the varied advice.

Answer (score 2):

How about (c): splitting the contents of the file on '\r' after you've read it with Python?

Comment: Python doesn't recognize Apple's "\r" delimiter, alas.

Comment: Python should, actually -- I assume the Python interpreter Apple ships is compiled with universal newline support, in which case a simple `.splitlines()` on the string should do the trick.

Comment: You can't just explicitly split a string on a character which happens to be '\r'?

Comment: Thanks, I am a python nub and .splitlines() worked just fine, I'm just a nub, henh, though ultimately the python-only solution above served me better than anything else. Thanks to everyone's input!

Answer (score 2):

How about (d): do the `mdfind` in Python?

```
import subprocess

command = "mdfind kMDItemKind=='*AppleWorks*'"
subpipe = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
outlist = subpipe.communicate()[0].splitlines()

for filename in outlist:
    print filename    # or whatever
```

NB: I'm not actually on a Mac at the moment but this worked OK for me with Windows and a `dir C:\` comamand, so it ought to work fine on a Mac with `mdfind`.

Comment: Well I immediately like this solution—I'm not really all that interested in AppleScript, but python throws an error. I've included the code as an edit to my initial question, see above (and thanks for the input).